# Racket - implementing functions to weighted sum

Tags: racket

I need to implement function that will show `#f` as result if lists `ws` and `vs` have different number of arguments.

code is:

```
(define (weighted-sum . ws)
  (define (sub . vs)
    (foldl
     (lambda (i j res) (+ res (* i j)))
     0
     ws
     vs))
  sub)
```

to be honest i have no idea have to even start

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `and` with the condition saying that both lists' lengths should be the same.

```
#lang racket

(define (weighted-sum . ws)
  (define (sub . vs)
    (and (= (length ws) (length vs)) ; <- ADDED
         (foldl (lambda (i j res) (+ res (* i j))) 0 ws vs)))                    
  sub)


; TESTS
(module+ test
  (require rackunit)

  (check-equal? ((weighted-sum)) 0)
  (check-equal?  ((weighted-sum 1 2 3 4) 10 20 30 40) 300)
  (check-equal? ((weighted-sum 1 2 3 4) 10 20 30) #f)
  (check-equal? ((weighted-sum 1 2) 10 20 30) #f))
```

**Edit:**

Here I bind the result in a `let` and then just check if it's equal to 1. If it is, the `and` will result in `result`, otherwise it will yield `#f`.

```
(define (weighted-sum . ws)
  (define (sub . vs)
    (and (= (length ws) (length vs))
         (let ([result (foldl (lambda (i j res) (+ res (* i j))) 0 ws vs)])
           (and (= result 1) result))))                    
  sub)
```

Note: `(if <some-condition> <then-expr> #false)` is equivalent to `(and <some-condition> <then-expr>)`

Comment: Can you please show me another thing? How to implicate function when the result is not equal to one, to show #f again. I dont know how to find out the result value to make any comparation. I am really sorry for bothering but racket is something totally different then I am used to.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you want to do exactly. What do you mean by "How to implicate function when the result is not equal to one, to show #f again."?

Comment: I need to compare result to one and find out if its true or not. when I really simplify it, I mean something like (if (= result 1)  result #f ).

Comment: I have edited the answer to include further explanation on how you may do that.

Comment: I am really grateful for your answer. Now I have to learn from it :)